Need a certain format for bibliographic entries
I want to format a reference like the one below. I use biblatex.

Wing, S., Johnson, J.R., Camporeale, E., Reeves, G.D., 2016. Information
theoretical approach to discovering solar wind drivers of the outer
radiation belt. J. Geophys. Res. Space Physics 121 (10), 9378–9399. https://doi.org/10.1002/2016JA022711

Code I write:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csquotes}% Recommended

\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}% Syntax for version >= 1.2

\author{WriteLaTeX}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

A citation  \textcite{ht} 

\printbibliography

\end{document}

result outcome:


Welcome te TeX.SE. What is the problem exactly? Which code do you have at the moment, what results does that give, how is it different from what you want?

Is your question related to the formatting of the citation call-out or to that of the bibliographic entry? Do please tell us how you generate the bibliographic material at present.

I modified my question to include the code that I wrote.

There are several major differences between what your preferred formatting style and what's produced by employing the authoryear-ibid style. And that's just for entries of type @article. Are you ok with the way the authoryear-ibid style formats entries of type @book, @techreport, etc? Please advise.

I want other styles similar to  article style

@article, @book, and @techreport, among others, are not "styles". Rather, they are entry types. The formatting that's applied to one entry type may not be applicable to other entry types. So far, you've expressed a preference for a style that should be applied to entries of type @article; however, you've said nothing yet about how other entry types should be formatted.
